# Is it possible to interrupt or cancel the trash-delete process?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, imac, trash

I am connected to the company server, onsite not remote, which is Windows based. When, in the OS finder, I go to delete a file or directory that resides on the window-based server, the trash progress panel appears as usual. Not infrequently it will just hang there appearing to be active but no progress occurs on the progress bar. So the X is chosen to stop or cancel the process. A new panel appears, and while appearing to be active, again, just hangs there indefinitely.

My lack of reputation prevents posting a screen shot - sorry.

The question then is this:
Is there a way via the Activity Monitor, Terminal, etc. to interrupt this deleting process in the Mac OS? Currently, I have to force shutdown and reboot to eradicate the ever-deleting panel.
Finder relaunch does not solve and only eliminates the finder until I force reboot.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks,
Pete
iMac, Mac OS X (10.6.8), i7-2.8ghz, 8gb ram

Comment: My windows network is working well, so I can't actually reproduce that, but I will suggest you try force ejecting the network share or just kill the Finder process. (You can post the url to the screenshots and people can edit it to pictures for you.)

Comment: billc, thanks for the advice. I ended up ejecting the shared server from the sidebar of a folder using the little eject icon next to the server name. There was some delay in letting go of the server but not near as long as empty trash progress bar. The other nice thing is once the shared server is unmounted I can turn around and remount via an alias to an item on that server. I had tried killing the Finder and that eventually led to a force shutdown and reboot.

Answer (score 8):

To abort the "Move to Trash" operation after trying to cancel it, do the following:

1. From the Apple menu choose **Force Quit**
2. Select **Finder** and click **Relaunch**

Answer (score -2):

**TO AVOID RELAUNCHING FINDER:**

Open the **Activity Monitor** utility and **force quit the Locum process**.

Enter your admin password when requested.

Comment: Why does this have two down votes with no comments as to why it is a bad solution?